# finding a function with 2 variables that has a limit equal to zero

Tags: limits, functions

I am trying to find a function with $2$ variables that have a limit equal to zero at the point $(0,0)$ if you check the limit by any straight line that gets to that point, but also the function doesn't have a limit at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Note that the fact that for all the straight lines limit is zero doesn't prove that the limit is zero. Maybe you could show what is the limit and what is your work on it.

Comment: it is a theoretical question I'm working on, I am trying to find out if this kind function even exist

Comment: of course we can construct many of suche examples

Comment: I would be happy to get an example or 2 :)

Comment: Perhaps you can get some inspiration from the first example given (below) and construct another one from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{yx^2}{y^2+x^4}$$
Verify that $f$ tends to $0$ along any straight line and try along the parabola $y=x^2$ as well.